# Is it possible to customize the "add text" placeholders which appear for optional fields with no value in Experience manager?

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, 2013-sp1

I have a schema, which includes a (multivalue) embedded schema field which contains Subheading (Text), Paragraph text (Rich Text), Image (Multimedia link) and Caption (text) fields, all of which are optional. So, for example a paragraph can contain only text, or only an image, or both, with an optional subheading and/or caption.

The problem is that that all the optional text fields appear as `<add text>` in Experience Manager so its not clear to the editor which field they are editing (especially in the case where a paragraph has no caption, and the following paragraph has no subheading or paragraph text - you get three `<add text>` lines in a row, and its kind of guesswork to get the right one). Is it possible to customize this placeholder text, so I could for example have `<add subheading>`, `<add body text>`, `<add caption>` etc?

Following on from this, it would also be helpful if the empty values were formatted in the correct way (for example my subheading is a `<h2>` element, so the  should appear formatted as `<h2>`). Is this possible without having empty tags in the published content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It's not possible to customize the placeholder-text OOTB. Only solution I see is a GUI extension. See this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152648/can-we-replace-the-add-text-labels-in-siteedit-2012-on-tridion-2011

2) In my environment (2011 SP1, HR2) the `<add text>` does appear in the expected format. 
I have a `<h2>` with inside the XPM MarkUp for a title: `<h2><!-- .... --> Title</h2>`. If this field is empty, the `<add text`> shows as a `<h2>` tag

If you can detect that you're in EditMode (serverside, which is possible) you could render this content yourself (pseudo-code):

```
if(InEditMode && string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
{
     title = "Add paragraph title";
}
```

The only disadvantage of this is, that if the editor clicks in this area, the helper text disappears (value from Tridion is placed inside this tag, which is empty) and then clicks away, without supplying a value, the `<add text>` message shows again.

Comment: I added an idea for this: http://ideas.sdltridion.com/ideas/detail.asp?i=4930